# Batch Copy Files from Inside Folder to Matching Folder in Destination

Tags: batch-file

I have files in a folder structure on one network drive and need to copy them via batch to another folder structure on a separate network drive.

I have a batch script that copies them from the source to the destination but it only copies them into the top-level, not into the folders.

Ex:

```
SOURCE
  newsletters
  |-2016
  |-2017
  |-2018

DESTINATION
  newsletters
  |-2016
  |-2017
  |-2018
```

My script copies the files inside the `SOURCE\newsletters\..` folders but only puts them into `DESTINATION\newsletters`, not inside the year folders:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R %G IN (*.pdf) DO xcopy "%G" "DESTINATION\newsletters"
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the output of `XCopy /?` to see if there were any options for copying directories containing files?

Comment: @Compo I tried adding `/E` and it does the same thing.

Comment: **`/E`**? I'm certain that there will be no empty directories containing `*.pdf` files! Would `/S` not have suited better?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with `ROBOCOPY`:

```
robocopy ./ DESTINATION\newsletters\ /E *.pdf
```